# broken usb port , adapting serial to usb

Tags: usb, serial, port

Dell Inspiron running Vista sp2 has broken USB port; can I obtain an adapter to use off the 9 pin serial port that will convert to USB? If so, will it be reliable or slow compared to USB 2.0?

Comment: No. It will be dog slow.

Comment: If it has ExpressCard or PCMCIA slot you can probably find some USB adapter for those. If you hope for more help, you should probably specify the precise Inspiron model.

Comment: [Serial ports commonly top out at 115,200 bits per second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port#Speed) (and such high speeds were often problematic, at least back in the days of common use of (RS-232) serial ports.) Compare this to USB, where even [USB 1.x Low Speed is 1,500,000 bits per second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_2.0#USB_1.x): the slowest possible speed for USB is >10x faster! USB 1.x Low Speed was intended for devices like keyboards and mice. USB 2.0 High Speed tops out at approximately 280 Mbit/s in practice, compared to the 0.115 Mbit/s for the serial port.

Answer (score 0):

One does not simply use a serial port as an alternative to a USB hub. USB is a relatively advanced technology, and a serial port simply does not match the sheer speed and reliability of USB.

That said, you need to find an ExpressCard or PCMCIA (called "CardBus" or "PC Card") card for USB.

Answer (score 0):

While there are many usb -> serial port adapters, I have never seen a serial port to USB adapter. Because of the way usb ports daisy chain, it would require a very sophisticated hardware adapter, and a complex software driver. It would also be very slow.

Comment: Could you give us a better description of your broken USB port? Does the connector have physical damage? Or does it simply not work when a device is plugged in? It could be as simple as re-installing the USB driver. Have you checked the device manager to verify the driver is installed?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to replace the broken USB port in your Inspiron.  Not all ports in all laptops can be replaced without replacing the entire motherboard, but it's not uncommon to find ports (like USB, audio, etc.) are on replaceable circuit boards separate from the mainboard.  If so, you may be able to find parts cheaply on eBay and do the repair yourself (following video instructions from YouTube) and restore your USB function without spending the prohibitive amount it would cost to pay a professional to repair your computer.